# Is there a way to remove screen flashing (flickering) when using NavHostController with Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, flicker, flashing

I am working on an Android application using **Kotlin** and **Jetpack Compose**. To switch between the different screens I am using the **NavHostController**.

Initialization:

```kt
private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

setContent {
    navController = rememberNavController()

    Theme {
        ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kt
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = *route*) {
    composable(route = *route*) {

    }

    composable(route = *route*) {

    }

    ...
}
```

In each `composable` I call `navController.navigate(route = *route*)` to switch between screens.

**EDIT (** I call the `navController.navigate()` inside a `ChildComposable`, which is inside the `composable`**).**

I use one `Activity` only, which has no background set. This is how I add a background image to all the screens:

```kt
@Composable
fun ContentWithBackground(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = R.drawable.background),
        contentDescription = "Logo",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )

    content()
}
```

The way I use the navigation causes **flashing** when the screens are changed and the new content is replacing the previous one. Basically, **flickering**. I guess this is somewhat of an expected behaviour.

However, is there a way to fix this? How can the change happen smoothly?

Here is a video of the *flashing*:

[Video hosted in streamable.com](https://streamable.com/cigpxt)

Comment: The NavHost does default to a cross fade animation between screens, but that _is_ a smooth transition. Is it the content of your screens that is flickering? What happens if you replace the contents of your screen with something static (e.g., just some placeholder text, etc.)? This seems like an issue with the implementation of your screen, which you haven't shared.

Comment: I just added how I implement my screens, which all have the same background image. I can add a very short video to show exactly how the screen is *flashing*

Comment: What color is the `windowBackground` of your activity? A crossfade involves both screens being semi-transparent by definition, so you will see the underlying `windowBackground` color...which I assume is the default bright white?

Comment: It must be the default white as I haven't changed it myself. I've tried setting it to the same background image the other screens have, but it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't pass the nav controller to your child composables instead hoist the state and navigate from the main activity.

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = *route*) {
    composable(route = *route*) {

        ChildComposable{
             navController.navigate("")
           }
    }

    composable(route = *route*) {

    }

    ...
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposable(
  navigate : () -> Unit
){
   Button(
    onClick = { navigate() }
   ){
  Text(text = "exit")
 }
}
```

2. Another reason can be that the background color of your activity differs from the composable's background color,you can remove the background from the composable and add it to the activity window.

**EDIT**

to change activity's background to an image you can use this

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
            LaunchedEffect(activity) {
                activity.window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.img)
            }
```

Comment: It does work the way you described in the first possible solution. As for your second idea, this might be a thing. All my content views have the same background image, but nothing is set to the initial activity.

Comment: did any of the changes work in your case?

Comment: With my previous comment I meant that I do use ```ChildComponents``` (I edited the question to make it more clear). I am not sure, though, how to change the ```Activity``` color as the other screens use a background image (please see the changes in the question). Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: then please consider accepting or atleast upvoting the answer

Comment: No solution is found. You bet I will if we do find such. :)

Comment: Where/When should I specifically execute this ```LaunchedEffect```? I've tried in both the *MainActivity.kt* and in the ```ChildComposable```s, but to no avail.

Comment: both the lines inside of the setContent block of your main activity

Comment: That's what I thought, but it didn't work out. :(  You can even check the video I added in the question.

Comment: I cannot find any other solution to it :___(